# Removing unwanted strings from numeric float pandas string column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that I harvested from wikipedia that has lat long coords as a col, and I'm trying to remove occurences of strings between parens that occur in **some** of the rows but not all.

Sample:

```
25     53.74333, 91.38583
47    -10.167, 148.700﻿ (Abau Airport)
155    16.63611, -14.19028
414    49.02528, -122.36000
1      16.01111, 43.17778
176    35.34167, 1.46667﻿ (Abdelhafid Boussouf Bou Ch...)
```

I've tried doing this

```
big_with_ll['Lat_Lon'] = big_with_ll['Lat_Lon'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('[^\d.]', '')))
```

Which throws this error, basically indicating that not all have characters to remove, which is fine but if I try implementing a for loop to use a try/catch then I'll have to map and in the case of this dataframe I don't have a unique ID to use as a key.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '53.58472, 14.90222'
```

Removing the float cast and doing this:

```
big_with_ll['Lat_Lon'] = big_with_ll['Lat_Lon'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('[^\d.]', ''))
```

The code executes, but no changes are made to which I'm not sure why.

The expected output should look like this:

```
25     53.74333, 91.38583
47    -10.167, 148.700﻿
155    16.63611, -14.19028
414    49.02528, -122.36000
1      16.01111, 43.17778
176    35.34167, 1.46667﻿
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple regex:

```
 df.Lat_Lon.str.extract('^([-\d\.,\s]+)')
```

Output:

```
                        0
25     53.74333, 91.38583
47       -10.167, 148.700
155   16.63611, -14.19028
414  49.02528, -122.36000
1      16.01111, 43.17778
176     35.34167, 1.46667
```

You can go as far as extracting both the latitude and longitude:

```
df.Lat_Lon.str.extract('^(?P<Lat>[-\d\.]+),\s(?P<Lon>[-\d\.]+)')
```

Output:

```
          Lat         Lon
25   53.74333    91.38583
47    -10.167     148.700
155  16.63611   -14.19028
414  49.02528  -122.36000
1    16.01111    43.17778
176  35.34167     1.46667
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using python's `str.replace` use pandas `DataFrame.replace` with `regex=True` option. So instead your line should be:

```py
big_with_l['Lat_Lon'] = big_with_ll['Lat_Lon'].replace(r'[^\d.]', '', regex=True)
```

Just a heads up, I assumed your regex string was well formed.